# Can't launch .exe

Tags: vb.net

Trying to make a "world of warcraft" launcher.

How it should work:
When you press " Start Authserver " you get to locate the authserver.exe. the location is then saved so you don't have to do that twice.
Once pressed, it obviously should launch the authserver.exe.

What happens:
When you press " Start Authserver " it opens and instantly closes with error:
Error, couldn't open cause authserver.conf couldn't be located.

Notice: 
Authserver.exe and authserver.conf is in the same folder, I'm able to launch it manually.

Mort helped me with similar problem yesterday, i hoped that the same VB code would work since that would seem obvious.

```
Private filePath As String = String.Empty

Private Sub PlayButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PlayButton.Click
    Try
        If filePath.Length = 0 Then
            Dim diagResult As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
            If diagResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                filePath = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
                If filePath.ToUpper.EndsWith("WOW.EXE") Then
                    Process.Start(filePath)
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong file selected!")
                    filePath = String.Empty
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Process.Start(filePath)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred in the play button click:", ex.Message))
    End Try

End Sub
```

Anyone got an idea?
In advance: Thanks.

Comment: You probably have the wrong working directory.

Comment: use `Process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory` to tell it where to start

Comment: Just checked, the directory is correct.

Comment: Im very new at VB, where should i put that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```html
    Private Sub PlayButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PlayButton.Click
        Try
            OpenFileDialog1.FileName = ""
            OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "World of Warcraft (WOW.EXE)|WOW.EXE"
            Dim diagResult As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog
            If diagResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                Dim p As New Process
                Dim fn As New System.IO.FileInfo(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
                p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = fn.DirectoryName
                p.StartInfo.FileName = fn.Name
                p.Start()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred in the play button click:", ex.Message))
        End Try
    End Sub
```